# Render Pug (Jade) on a browser (exmp. Google Chrome , Mozilla Firefox)

Tags: html, browser, pug

I am new to Pug aka Jade and what i want is to parse a file.pug 
to a web browser like Google Chrome.

Following this [(Pug on github)](https://github.com/pugjs/pug#jade1),
i installed pug but when i create a file.html and file.pug
the pug doesn't render the tags to html.

What is needed to make this happen ?

Comment: For people who found this question and actually did want to render Pug *in a browser*, client-side: it is possible! [Here's the README section on it.](https://github.com/pugjs/pug?tab=readme-ov-file#browser-support)

Answer (score 3):

PUG (or JADE) is a pre-processor that needs to be compiled to html. This means that you need a proper compile module to do that.

As given on the example at https://pugjs.org/api/getting-started.html

Best option is to install "pug" module from NPM

For that to work you first need to have installed NODEjs (from https://nodejs.org/en/)

then its only running the npm install commands to get PUG and PUG client:

```
npm i pug
npm i pug-cli
```

After that please refer to the PUG getting started website as stated above for quite easy and detail explanation of the process of using PUG:

https://pugjs.org/api/getting-started.html

Comment: If I need to quickly make a prototype and I don't want to use Gulp, can I render pug in browser?

Comment: I don't think that's possible (I have not researched it, but it goes against the idea of pre-processed languages). As an update to my previous answer, there are a thousand new ways to render PUG now I personally am used to using extensions on my editors, that just automate the process. 
Also, the upper answer actually does not advice using gulp or any task tool for that matter. Pug itself has a watch command that works perfectly.